Trying to free up space from my mac os, especially the others sector

Emptied the Trash

sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*


Removed System and User Cache Files

sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/*/


Removed System and User Log Files

sudo rm -rf /Library/Logs/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/*

My "other" part of drive is still huge, any more ideas ?

Edit:
This is my mac specs:


Don't remove caches. They will just fill back up, and likely aren't what is being reported here.

@benwiggy so what do you suggest ? when it was new others was tiny now others is 30x bigger than system. This is how OmniDiskSweeper looks.

As in the linked question, use an app like OmniDiskSweeper, which will sort your disk by size, allowing you to see what is taking up the space.

@benwiggy This is how OmniDiskSweeper looks.

Give it time to complete the search.


You probably have automatic snapshots (created by TM or similar) which still contain the deleted data. They will go away in 24 hours, but for now are part of the "Other". 2) OmniDiskSweeper is not really good enough for recent macOS system disks - better to use DaisyDisk which will make a better attempt to dissect the Other.


I don't agree with the Close if this is for a recent macOS version. The linked question is very old and the internals of macOS system disks have changed considerably. macOS 10.12 (Sierra) used a different format disk.

@Gilby ODS has been updated recently, and seems to work well for me. It is free, too. Are we sure that snapshots are contained in "Other" (which I don't have on Sonoma, only "System Data", which Apple defines as "anything not in the other categories"...!)

I have just realised from your screenshot that you are using an oldish version of macOs on a SATA disk. Please modify the question to make it clear what version of macOS and something about your Mac model and storage. My references to snapshots may be irrelevant for your macOS.
